# ionic build Android | CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8.x! Detected version: 512.0.0

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, sdk, ionic-native

```
    CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8.x! Detected version: 512.0.0
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
    at Object.module.exports.check_java (E:\QSET\user_app\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:145:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --verbose exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 2 functions +1ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 8768: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 8768 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "8768" not found.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
  ionic:utils-process     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:674:12) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 8768 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +2s
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 8768 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "8768" not found.
```

**when I'm running ionic build android I'm getting the above error**

I've tried to update my Gradle + SDK
The Java Home variable is setted correctly to the JDK path, but I don't know why I am getting this issue. Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, I solved it by following the instruction in this link link: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/29/cordova-android-9.0.0.html

(I use cordova android 10)

then remove and add again android platform

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30239217)